# How to disable ( readonly ) other inputtext when keypressed in inputtext

Tags: jsf

I have `<h:form>` that looks like this:

```
            <h:form>
                <h:outputLabel>MDM ID:</h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="searchIdMaster" value="#{tdetail.id_master}"></h:inputText>

                <h:outputLabel>Poslovni partner id:</h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="searchPoslovniPartnerId"  value="#{tdetail.poslovni_partner_id}"></h:inputText>

                <h:outputLabel>JMBG:</h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="searchJMBG" value="#{tdetail.jmbg}"></h:inputText>

                <h:outputLabel>PIB:</h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="searchPIB" value="#{tdetail.pib}"></h:inputText>

                <h:outputLabel>MBR:</h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="searchMBR" value="#{tdetail.mbr}"></h:inputText>

                <h:commandButton value="Search " action="#{tdetail.search()}">
                    <f:ajax execute="searchIdMaster searchPoslovniPartnerId searchJMBG searchPIB searchMBR"  render="outputIdMaster outputPoslovniPartnerId outputJMBG outputPIB outputMBR"></f:ajax>
                </h:commandButton>
                <h2>
                    <h:outputLabel>MDM ID:</h:outputLabel>
                    <h:outputText id="outputIdMaster" value="#{tdetail.id_master}"></h:outputText>
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputLabel>Poslovni partner id:</h:outputLabel>
                    <h:outputText id="outputPoslovniPartnerId" value="#{tdetail.poslovni_partner_id}"></h:outputText>
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputLabel>JMBG:</h:outputLabel>
                    <h:outputText id="outputJMBG" value="#{tdetail.jmbg}"></h:outputText>
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputLabel>PIB:</h:outputLabel>
                    <h:outputText id="outputPIB" value="#{tdetail.pib}"></h:outputText>
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputLabel>MBR:</h:outputLabel>
                    <h:outputText id="outputMBR" value="#{tdetail.mbr}"></h:outputText>
                </h2>
            </h:form>
```

Here is a picture for better understanding:
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fxEF.jpg)

When user starts typing in one of the first 3 `<h:inputText>` other should be disabled. If typing in one of the last 2  only first 3 should be disabled. If text deleted ( empty ) enable all fields.

(User can search by MDM ID only or Poslovni partner id only or JMBG only or both PIB and MBR, I hope you understand )

I found similar question but there is no solution for my problem.

Comment: What did you try so far? And what is your problem?

Comment: didn't try anything.. i don't know how to do that, i need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution..

```
                <h:outputLabel>MDM ID:</h:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText id="searchIdMaster" value="#{tdetail.id_master}">
                    <p:ajax event="keyup" update="searchJMBG searchPoslovniPartnerId" />
                </p:inputText>

                <h:outputLabel>Poslovni partner id:</h:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText id="searchPoslovniPartnerId"  value="#{tdetail.poslovni_partner_id}" disabled="#{not empty tdetail.id_master}"></p:inputText>

                <h:outputLabel>JMBG:</h:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText id="searchJMBG" value="#{tdetail.jmbg}" disabled="#{not empty tdetail.id_master}"></p:inputText>
```

Use ajax and in the update attribute put space-separated list of compnent id you want to update and `disabled="#{not empty bean.property }"`